# how can i use my config.ini file instead of hard coding the folder name that i am getting my attachment file from?

Tags: python, config

```
for fileName in os.listdir('attachments'):
    hot_file_path = os.path.join('attachments', fileName)
    with open(hot_file_path, "r") as csv_file:
        hot_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

what i am trying to do is check the 'attachments' folder and get the name of any files that i have within it, right now i am using a hard coded path but i am wondering how i could use my config.ini file instead. I have been successful with using the config.ini for my database credentials. any help would be appreciated

```
for fileName in config['files']['folder_path']:
    hot_file_path = config['files']['folder_path'] + fileName
```

this is the way i tried to use it but it is not pointing to the correct directory, let me know if i can give more info to help

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the module `configparser`?

Comment: yes that is what i am using, when i replace 'os.listdir' with 'config['files']['folder_path] it isnt the correct value that i am expecting. Im wondering if i have the wrong format or how i can write it with os.listdir?

Comment: `config['files']['folder_path]` returns a folder name, which is a *string*. When your code iterates through that, what it gets is each letter in the string. `os.listdir()` returns a *list*. When your code iterates through that, it gets the name of each file in that folder. Naming a folder in a config file simply names the folder: it is not shorthand for every file in that folder. Are you maybe looking for `os.listdir(config['files']['folder_path])`?

Comment: oh i see, that seems to be working now, one more question. for the next line of hot_file_path i need to be adding the fileName var to the end of my folder, do you know how i would write that line while still using 'fileName' ?

Comment: never mind i can figure it out on my own time, thank you so much for the help!!